# Is "You're damn right it is." correct grammatically? Whether right or not, would you give me an explanation about this line, please?

Tags: conjunctions, clauses

I would like to ask you a question about a line from a movie.

> You're damn right it is.

The above line is from the tail-part *(Is this word proper? maybe 'back' or 'last' would be right instead of 'tail'. Please would you also let me know about this?)* of the movie, Spit on Your Grave 3.
It is what the angry female main character says.

Is that sentence correct grammatically? It looks like it consists of two clauses.
Is a conjunction **"that"** omitted in between "right" and "it"?

Thank you.

Comment: "tail part of the movie" is ok, but perhaps "near the end of the movie" is simpler.

Comment: @SmartHumanism Just in case you don't know, "damn" as used here is an expletive that intensifies the sense of "right." The expletive would not be used in "polite" language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct that it is two clauses, with an omitted complementiser "that". This is often omitted after verbs like "think" and "say", and adjectives like "certain". It seems to me that it's less often omitted after "right", but it certainly can be.

Comment: Thank you for the solution! Now I know for sure that the sentence consists of two clauses and 'the' plays a role as a complementizer! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

*Damn* is one of those curse words that has become quite versatile, like the F-word (if you are familiar with its uses). It is not considered polite language, but I would say that it is certainly not as vulgar/rude as the F-word.

In this case, my first impression was that *damn* means *absolutely* here.

> You're **absolutely** right it is.

But using the word *damn* here gives it a somewhat tough, aggressive feeling. I (we) would need to watch the movie to verify.

You can include a *that* between *right* and *it* without changing the meaning.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer. Though, I would like to get an answer a little bit more focused on 'that' and the construction of the sentence.